# Is there a way to prevent TeamCity from checking all VCSRoots?

Tags: version-control, teamcity

We have a substantial number of components, and every time a build is kicked off, TeamCity checks all VCSRoots for changes. We have some 200+ VCSRoots.  This adds a fair amount of time to the startup time of a build.

So, is there any way to prevent this, and just have TC check the repo that is attached to the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before each build TeamCity collects changes in all VCS roots attached to the build configuration directly, all roots from dependencies and also roots configured for [Versioned settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control).

If possible you can try to reduce the number of VCS roots. It's recommended to have small number of VCS roots, pointing to the root of the repository, and to use [checkout rules](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Rules) to define what to check out.

Comment: I was unaware of the Dependencies........ That might be the bomb.  Thanks.  If that's it, I'll be back.

Comment: It is dependencies, and there's nothing to be done about it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

To your point, yes [Teamcity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Roots) will always monitor VCS Roots once they are created.

> Once a VCS root is configured, TeamCity regularly queries the version
>   control system for new changes and displays the changes in the Build
>   Configurations that have the root attached.

You mention that you have 200+ VCS Roots.

Question: do you have 200+ builds?

If yes, then I suggest streamlining your roots to watch only the necessary folders in the repo tree, or reusing [VCS Roots](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Settings).

> TeamCity performs VCS-related operations per each VCS root separately,
>   thus it is advised to reuse VCS roots with same settings.

If no, and I'm assuming this is not the case, then delete unused roots. You can see which VCS Roots are not being used from the Administrator tab.

With that many builds you should be using a few agents. If you are not, then I recommend adding some. I think the free license allows up to three.

Comment: yes, we've got 200+ builds.  consolidation is on the table, but not possible at present.  The VCSRoots all look at their own tree, no extraneous tree's monitored.  The VCSRoots are parameterised, so maybe that's the issue.  i'll check that.  24 agents.

Comment: ok then, while you wait for consolidation and having 24 agents I think you can afford to eliminate the Teamcity server as an agent itself, and leave it to act as just a server. That will definitely soften the load a bit. It will still monitor all the roots but it wont spend any time running builds, but rather launching them in their respective qualified agents. Just a thought.

Comment: exactly what it's doing.  it's a super powered machine for just doing that, but that's all it does currently, and given the build chain dependencies, it sometimes struggles to do that in any timely manner. :-s

Comment: this is a tough one. To be honest though, I cannot image TC using so much computer power to just monitor 200+ roots as all it does is query the  VSC server every 60 seconds by default. I can't imagine a request taking longer than a few milliseconds at most. But say that 200+ requests take all of one second. Then all this server is going to have to time to do is monitor the VCS. Can you change the default from 60 to say a few minutes depending on the build?

Comment: I suspect it's just the time that our SVN repo takes to respond that takes up the time.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this is to disable TeamCity from checking the changes in the VSC root but instead use a web hook call to notify TeamCity that there are changes in the source control repository. Then you can also configure a trigger to only trigger your build if files in a certain directory have changed. Hope this helps.

Comment: agreed, did think of that, but we're not in control of the subversion repos. so not really an option.

Comment: how to disable teamcity from checking the changes in the vcsroot